# Angular - Observable change detected in component's controller but not in its' template

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, rxjs, observable, angular-template

**SECOND EDIT:**

So! I've figured out the issue, but in-order to understand the problem you must first understand the goal:

I'm currently working on an `Angular Chrome-Extension` which has a persistent background script (unlike all the examples & tutorials I found which explain only non-persistent background script - or Event Page [Example](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/software-tools/developing-google-chrome-extension-using-angular-4/)).

The background script is actually an Angular component which holds the `logic service` which should be accessible in the different chrome components (popup, options, etc..)

1. When injecting the logic service using the naive Angular DI method things start to get messy because from chrome's perspective, the background script page & the popup script page has a different `window` object which leads in having 2 instances of the application, 1 in the 'background window' and another in the 'popup window'.
2. When using chrome's API `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` to acquire the service in the popup I get the right instance but now another issue occurs, changes in the background service doesn't reflect because the service is outside of Angular's app context.

**So I have a new question which is:**

Is it possible to tell Angular to 'add/watch' an Angular service that was not instantiated by it and add it to the application context?

**EDITED:**
I've added the 2 services, It seems like I have a deeper problem in my project because this demo code works as expected.. will keep on updating when resolved.

**The Original Question**

I'm trying to pass async data from a parent component to a child component & I run into some issues.

The service holds an observable & the parent subscribes to it + passing it via `async` pipe to the child's input.

The problem is that the parent picks on the changes (only from the controller) & none of the UI is updated.

I can trigger `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` within the subscribe function but it seems to me like a very strange thing because the `async` pipe should've picked up on those changes but it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Consider the following code (This works as expected as a new project):

**Parent component:**

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: '<div>
                <button (click)="logic.doAction()">Get data</button>
                <child [someInput]="logic.data$ | async"></child>
                <div>data: {{logic.data$ | async | json}}</div>
             </div>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
     constructor(public logic: LogicService) {}
}
```

**Child component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<span>{{someInput}}</child>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() someInput: string;
    constructor() {}
}
```

**Logic service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class LogicService {
  private readonly dataSubject: BehaviorSubject<Array<string>>;
  private readonly _data$: Observable<Array<string>>;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    this.dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this._data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
  }

  doAction(): void {
    this.api.fetchFromAPI().then((data) => this.dataSubject.next(data));
  }

  get data$(): Observable<Array<string>> {
    return this._data$;
  }
}
```

**API service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  fetchFromAPI(): Promise<Array<string>> {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setInterval(() => {
        res(['some', 'demo', 'data']);
      }, 4000);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't subscribe to the observable?

Comment: You're subscribing **three times** to the observable from the parent. Do you really want that? Anyway, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: What code does emit the event to the observable? If the code that emits the events runs outside Angulars zone, then there won't any change detection be executed.

Comment: @ConnorsFan it doesn't matter, the ui updates only after i trigger some event in the UI (like a click)

Comment: Is it possible for you to show the service?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I run into simular issues with Observable | async in the view...

Comment: @ElgervanBoxtel yes i've created a directive that forces a view refresh when an observable is changed, will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've created a directive that forces a view update when an observable is updated.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[detectChanges]'
})
export class DetectChangesDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  @Input('detectChanges') observable$: Observable<any>;


  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.observable$.subscribe((() => {
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Using it is very easy, just  apply it to the view that you're having update issues with like so:

```
<div [detectChanges]="logic.data$">
  <button (click)="logic.doAction()">Get data</button>
  <child [someInput]="logic.dataValue"></child>
  <div>data: {{logic.dataValue | json}}</div>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT:**

1. Notice that I no longer use the `async` pipe & instead i'm passing the actual value to where I bind it.
2. I pass the `Observable` to the directive which keeps track when the value changes

Answer (score 0):

IMO, if a service method returns an observable, it should be unwrapped (subscribed to) at the place where the data is needed. I'd do it as follows:

```
<child [someInput]="service.observable"></child>
```

And in the child:

```
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() someInput: Observable;
    // subscribe to someInput in the child
}
```

Comment: That's bad practice in my opinion. The async pipe should be used whenever possible. The child component gets also much more reusable when not consuming an observable.

Comment: I agree with @DavidIbl, IMO a 'dumb' component shouldn't handle async data